# Call useSubscription after loading the state value

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, subscription, graphql-subscriptions

```
const {authState,loading:authLoading}=useAuthState();
const {
        data,
        loading,
        error
    } = useSubscription(USER_NOTIFICATIONS, { variables: { userId:authState.userId} });
```

In the above code, I am getting

**Cannot read property 'userId' of null** because the authState is null when the component loads.

Is there any way to call the useSubscription hook only after the authState is loaded and it is not empty.

I read useSubscription apollo document, there is an attribute named **skip** which accepts a boolean value.

Is **skip** will solve this issue? In that case, Is there any code example available?

I cant use like this, because this is against react hooks

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
         if(await authState){
           const {
             data,
             loading,
             error
           } = useSubscription(USER_NOTIFICATIONS, { variables: { userId:authState.userId}});
         }
        }
        if(!authLoading) fetchData();
     }, [authState,authLoading])
```